# Azure AD: Self service password reset using graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to trigger self service password reset for a user in Azure AD using Graph API. What I want to achieve is, an API call which can trigger this and a password reset link should be sent to the user's alternate email address.

I know this is possible from https://passwordreset.microsoftonline.com/ where the user enters the username and captcha. Although my requirement needs me to do this from my custom app without redirecting to the passwordreset.microsoftonline.com site.

I tried [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#ResetUserPassword) API for password reset:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version
{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "password": "Test123456",
    "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
  }
}
```

It returned me a 204. However, I am not sure what this API did. I am still able to login using the old Password for the user. Does this API send a password recovery email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That API does not send any emails. The way you have set it up is that *Test123456* should be the new password. It's a bit odd that the API gave you a success but still let you log in with the old password.

If you want to send an email, you have to do that manually currently, the API does not support it.

I would also suggest that you set `forceChangePasswordNextLogin` to `true` so the password sent in the email is only valid on next login so even if someone gets the email later they can't do anything with it.